# Get a flat RDD from RDD with nested elements in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce

I have two RDD in Pyspark with nested elements like these:

```py
a = sc.parallelize(( (1,2), 3,(4,(6,7,(8,9,(11),10)),5,12)))

b = sc.parallelize(1,2,(3,4))
```

The nesting can have any depth.

I want to union them and then find the maximum element in any depth, so i tried to transform it into RDD without having nested values like this (1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,10,5,12,1,2,3,4) and get the maximum, using any of these (map, reduce, filter, flatmap, lamda function). Can anyone tell me how to transform or get the maximum element.

I have came with a solution but it works only for two level of depth like

```
a = sc.parallelize(( (1,2), 3,(4,5)))
b = sc.parallelize((2,(4,6,7),8))

def maxReduce(tup):
    return int(functools.reduce(lambda a,b : a if a>b else b, tup))

maxFunc = lambda x: maxReduce(x) if type(x) == tuple else x

a.union(b).map(lambda x: maxFunc(x)).reduce(lambda a,b : a if a>b else b)
```

The above code works only for depth two, I need to work it for any given depth `(1,(2,3,(4,5,(6,(7,(8))))))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds a good use case for recursive function:

```
from collections import Iterable

a = sc.parallelize(((1, 2), 3, (4, (6, 7, (8, 9, (11), 10)), 5, 12)))
b = sc.parallelize((1, 2, (3, 4)))

def maxIterOrNum(ele):
    """
    this method finds the maximum value in an iterable otherwise return the value itself
    :param ele: An iterable of numeric values or a numeric value
    :return: a numeric value
    """
    res = -float('inf')
    if isinstance(ele, Iterable):
        for x in ele:
            res = max(res, maxIterOrNum(x))
        return res
    else:
        return ele

a.union(b).reduce(lambda x, y: max(maxIterOrNum(x), maxIterOrNum(y)))
```